# How to get payment amount from Stripe token? (in PHP)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've got a site that offer users 3 different subscription plans (with 3 different prices). So there's a sign up page with 3 different subscribe buttons, each of which opens Stripe Checkout for the appropriate amount for each plan (I'm using the standard Stripe simple Checkout integration https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple ) .

On my server I know which plan a user has subscribed to because I've got a hidden field in each Stripe Checkout button form with the plan name. The problem is how to stop someone editing the form (e.g. using developer tools in their browser) and changing the hidden plan field so they get e.g. the Gold plan at the Basic plan price.

The obvious solution seemed to be to check the amount associated with the stripeToken that Stripe returns (i.e. the same as the data-amount field in the Stripe Checkout form), before calling the Stripe API to actually subscribe the user. However, I'm not sure how to get the amount from Stripe using just the token and can't find an obvious API call for this.

Or is there some better way of handling multiple subscription plan options while ensuring a user can't somehow get away with paying a lesser amount?

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just base your user access on the subscription that Stripe returns on the backend? For instance, if they spoof your form to submit "Basic" after they selected "Gold", the backend should sign them up for "Basic" and they are granted the permissions of a Basic subscription. If they change the form value to a plan that doesn't exist, then the backend throws an exception and the whole thing is cancelled.

Comment: @Spartacus yeah on further thought that sounds good, and is probably the obvious solution. Thanks

Comment: That's what I did with my implementation, so that's where the suggestion comes from. Tried to make it spoof-proof as much as possible, everything is sanitized on the backend.

Comment: I find it weird that Stripe lets you charge any amount to a token that you can show a 50 cent charge to